# how to print same value as entered in above textbox

Tags: php, html

The user is asked to enter his/her name and the same name should be displayed in the username asked below by default.
I have tried this code, but it doesn't help me out!

```
<tr>
        <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">Manager  Name   :</td>
        <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName" type="TEXT" id="ManagerName" size="40"  maxlength="100">                </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">UserName   :</td>
        <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName" type="TEXT" value="<?php echo ManagerName ?>" size="40"  maxlength="100">                </td>
      </tr>
```

Please help me out!

Comment: `echo ManagerNam` well for one thing; if you haven't defined that constant, you'll get just that; `undefined constant ManagerNam.... on line X` - Post to self (or use ajax) with an echo'd ternary'd operator with variables. Variables btw, start with the `$` sign.

Comment: Thank you for helping me......But if u could alter the code and provide me it will be better......one more thing Please try the level best to alter this code without MSQL

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script>
document.getElementById('ManagerName').addEventListener('blur', function() {
    document.getElementById('ManagerName2').value = this.value;
});
</script>
<tr>
        <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">Manager  Name   :</td>
        <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName" type="TEXT" id="ManagerName" size="40"  maxlength="100">                </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">UserName   :</td>
        <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName2" type="TEXT" value="" size="40"  maxlength="100">                </td>
      </tr>
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to do this with javascript:

```
<tr>
    <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">Manager Name:</td>
    <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName" type="TEXT" id="ManagerName" size="40"  maxlength="100">
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="TrackMediumBlue" align="right" width="138">UserName:</td>
    <td width="13">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="477">
        <input name="ManagerName" type="TEXT" id="ManagerName2" size="40"  maxlength="100">
    </td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('ManagerName').addEventListener('blur', function() {
        document.getElementById('ManagerName2').value = this.value;
    });
</script>
```

Add an `id` attribute to the second input. In the exemple above I use `ManagerName2`.

**Edit:** all code together.

Comment: This is a good solution. However, all things considered, I think the OP might not know know how to embed Javascript in the HTML. Perhaps you should include the script tags and mention where to include it.

Comment: So the code will go as i answered to my own question

Comment: Thankyou VeryMuch Sir